# If a property in elasticsearch is neither indexed nor stored and the _source is also disabled, does the property affect storage space?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
POST /twitter/tweet/_mapping
{
  "tweet" : {
    "_source" : {"enabled" : false},
    "properties" : {
      "user" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "no", "store" : false}
    }
  }
}

POST /twitter/tweet/1
{
  "user": "John Doe"
}
```

Using the above _mapping and document, will the property value "John Doe" be stored anywhere by elasticsearch?

Also, apart from being displayed in the _mapping, is there any other role of the 'user' property?

Answer (score 0):

I was investigating the same doubt. As per ES documentation (1) in your case the original json you 'index' should be stored but the ES index will not contain any reference to that field.

store:
Set to true to actually store the field in the index, false to not store it. Defaults to false (note, the JSON document itself is stored, and it can be retrieved from it).

1. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html